# How to make “text-overflow: ellipsis” work with another floating element

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="card-content"> 
  <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">
    Anohana: The Flower We Saw That Day
    <i class="material-icons right">comment</i> 
  </span>
  <p>あの日見た花の名前を僕達はまだ知らない。</p>
</div>
```

`<i class="material-icons right">comment</i>` has a `float:right` property.

When text "Anohana: The Flower We Saw That Day" is too long it looks like this:
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td54c.png)

I want when text "Anohana: The Flower We Saw That Day" is too long it shows as ellipsis, like this:
[Hope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz7P.png)

So I added CSS like this:

```
.card-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Unfortunately, it shows like this now:
[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKJEt.png)

You see I wanna the icon show in one line with the title. Dear Stackoverflower, how can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. you can adjust the **width and icon position** using below css.

```css
.card-title i {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    right: 0;
}

.card-title {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<p class="card-title">
    Anohana: The Flower We Saw That Day
  <i>icon</i>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.. I change the `<span>` to `<div>` and add with on your css.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/LQpoOm)

```css
.card-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-title">
    Anohana: The Flower We Saw That Day
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Still not work in my situation. Anyway, thank you very much! ^_^